# My application breaks phone or some other apps' Notification Icon, Android

Tags: android

I have an interesting problem, my phone model is LGP800 and Android 4.1.2.
I'm developing an application and i'm using camera in this application. When I capture any photo for post, my phone behaves abnormally and other signs (notification icons of apps) also get broke sometimes. I can't find problem like this that nobody hasn't confronted it before. [An example secreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3EQS.png)

Like this picture, my application shows some weird screen or even phone's other apps' notification icon get broke by my application. Example; my wi-fi icon on the tab bar was broken.

Can anyone help, any help is appreciated.!

And also when I capture any picture, it is taken like that; [image: example]

İt is taken broke, too.

Comment: Did you tested your application in any other mobile devices? Does it show the same issue?

Comment: is your problem always or sometimes? it maybe because the camera driver would not have been initialized properly sometimes. Also clean your phone's RAM and try opening camera once

Comment: It is only on my phone, may be sometimes in S4, twice since I was started this application. But generally I have big broken on my phone. Not only wi-fi symbol. Sometimes my screen is completely broken. @AkhileshBChandran

Comment: it is sometimes @VivekKN but fifty percent I correspond this issue. I will try this, thank you.

Comment: Only using default camera @Coeus